# How to pass a object from ajax to the server in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I've got two models, there are.

```
public class CreateAssignmentViewModel {
    ...
    public List<CreateAssignmentSelectedItem> SelectedItems { get; set; }
}

public class CreateAssignmentSelectedItem {
    ...
}
```

Now I've got a view where contains `CreateAssignmentViewModel`, as you can see above this class contains a property where is a `List<CreateAssignmentSelectedItem>`

```
@model Contoso.MvcApplication.Models.Assignment.CreateAssignmentViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create Assignment";
    ...
}

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    ...
}
```

Inside of the `Html.BeginForm`, I've got a partial view. And in it I've got a button using ajax where updates the partial view.

Look the following events. Where says data: I do not know what to enter to access only the property `SelectedItems`

```
var addQuestionToAssignmentContent = function (questionId)
{
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Assignment/AddItemToAssignmentContent",
        type: "post",
        data: { model: $(this).serialize() /* HERE I DON'T KNOW TO ACCESS THE */, itemId: questionId },
        success: function (response) {
            var $target = $("#assignmentContent");
            var $newHtml = response;
            $target.replaceWith($newHtml);
        }
    });
};

    public ActionResult AddItemToAssignmentContent(List<CreateAssignmentSelectedItem> model, string itemId)
    {
        ...
        PartialView(..);
    }
```

How can I do to pass only the object in the method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, give your form an ID:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("actionName", "controllerName", FormMethod.Post, new{id = "frmUpdate"})) {
```

Second, change your code to be like this:

```
var f = $("#frmUpdate");
    $.ajax({
        url: f.attr('action'),
        type: f.attr('method'),
        data: f.serialize(),
        //etc..
```

I use this in most cases and it works just nice. The data should automatically be bound to the model you have in your update action. So, for example... if you have a `@model` of type `MyModel` then in the update action it should look something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Update(MyModel updatedModel)
```

Comment: So when I do a post, always should be te same model like in the razor view?

Comment: I haven't tried it, but I don't see why you couldn't use a different model. You would just need to make sure your serialized data matches whatever the Update action is expecting. However, why would you pass a different model? Usually one would create a model for editing and then send that same model to the Update action.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I work with a front end guy and he might not adhere to pass in the correct  model, he might  change the form fields or whatever.  In this case I just let him serialize the form and pass it to the action an any way he wants.

I then use the FormCollection object to get the data I need.

Your json call

```
var addQuestionToAssignmentContent = function (questionId)
{
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Assignment/AddItemToAssignmentContent",
        type: "post",
        data: { model: $(this).serialize() /* HERE I DON'T KNOW TO ACCESS THE */, itemId: questionId },
        success: function (response) {
            var $target = $("#assignmentContent");
            var $newHtml = response;
            $target.replaceWith($newHtml);
        }
    });
};
Get a form collection object

[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult AddItemToAssignmentContent(FormCollection collection)
{
       vars someValue = collection.GetValue("somefield").AttemptedValue;
}
```

But if I would have control of front-end as you do then  as Matt suggested you should use an pass a model;